# different versions of openssl installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: shared-library, openssl

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, the command

```
openssl version
```

gives the Output

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018
```

but the following path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0`
suggests I have an older version of the library installed. Can I update the library (i.e. the shared objects) without affecting the binary? Not having the latest openssl library might be related to the problem of not getting the MySql connector for C++ to work, so any hints would be highly appreciated. Thanks!